# Registering Child IOptions in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, configuration, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following configuration setup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(configuration);
}

public class AppSettings
{
    public ChildSettings Child { get; set; }

    public string Property { get; set; }
}

public class ChildSettings
{
    public string ChildProperty { get; set; }
}
```

My appSettings.json looks like this:

```
{
    "Child": {
        "ChildProperty": "Value"
    }
    "Property": "Value"
}
```

I can inject `IOptions<AppSettings>` into my controllers just fine:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController(IOptions<AppSettings> options)
    {
        ChildSettings appSettings = options.Value;
    }
}
```

It get's a little old having to go down a few levels to get to the settings object you want. Is there a way I can use `IOptions<ChildSettings>` like so:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController(IOptions<ChildSettings> options)
    {
        ChildSettings appSettings = options.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use ChildSettings directly without going via the AppSettings object, you must register ChildSettings as a separate entry in your DI configuration like this:

`services.Configure<ChildSettings>(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:ChildSettings"));`

But if you want to do this, perhaps you could just have ChildSettings at the root level of your appsettings.json file? You are not required to have your settings in a section named AppSettings.

Answer (score 0):

Configure all [options automatically](https://github.com/tchelidze/Register.Options.Asp.Net.Core)

```
PM> Install-Package Register.Options.Asp.Net.Core
```

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureOptionsFromAssemblies(configuration, new List<Assembly>()
    {
        typeof(AppSettings).Assembly
    });

    ...
}
```

*appsettings.json*

```
{
    "ChildSettings": {
        "ChildProperty": "Value"
    }       
}
```

*Disclaimer author of [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Register.Options.Asp.Net.Core/)*

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved by implementing a custom IOptionsFactory<>.

Copy-pastable code:

Usage: `services.AddRecursiveOptions<AppSettings>(Configuration);`

```cs
public static class RecursiveOptionsFactoryExtensions
{
    public static void AddRecursiveOptions<TAppSettings>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        where TAppSettings : class
    {
        var appSettings = configuration.Get<TAppSettings>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAppSettingsProvider>(
            new AppSettingsProvider<TAppSettings>(appSettings!));
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IOptionsFactory<>), typeof(RecursiveResolvingOptionsFactory<>));
        services.Configure<TAppSettings>(configuration);
    }


    private interface IAppSettingsProvider
    {
        public object AppSettings { get; }
    }

    private class AppSettingsProvider<TAppSettings> : IAppSettingsProvider
    {
        public object AppSettings { get; }

        public AppSettingsProvider([DisallowNull] TAppSettings appSettings)
        {
            AppSettings = appSettings ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appSettings));
        }
    }

    private class RecursiveResolvingOptionsFactory<TOptions> : IOptionsFactory<TOptions> where TOptions : class, new()
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<IConfigureOptions<TOptions>> _setups;
        private readonly IEnumerable<IPostConfigureOptions<TOptions>> _postConfigures;
        private readonly IEnumerable<IValidateOptions<TOptions>>? _validations;
        private readonly object _appSettings;

        public RecursiveResolvingOptionsFactory(
            IEnumerable<IConfigureOptions<TOptions>> setups,
            IEnumerable<IPostConfigureOptions<TOptions>> postConfigures,
            IEnumerable<IValidateOptions<TOptions>>? validations,
            IAppSettingsProvider appSettings)
        {
            _setups = setups;
            _postConfigures = postConfigures;
            _validations = validations;
            _appSettings = appSettings.AppSettings;
        }

        private static TOptions? FindOptionsRecursively(object source)
        {
            var properties = source.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(source);
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(TOptions))
                {
                    return (TOptions) value!;
                }

                if (!propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass || propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var found = FindOptionsRecursively(value!);
                if (found != null)
                {
                    return found;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public TOptions Create(string name)
        {
            // instead of creating default instance, like Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory<> does,
            // try finding if it is a property of AppSettings first
            var options = FindOptionsRecursively(_appSettings);
            if (options != null) return options;

            options = new TOptions();

            // copied from Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory<>
            foreach (IConfigureOptions<TOptions> setup in _setups)
            {
                if (setup is IConfigureNamedOptions<TOptions> configureNamedOptions)
                    configureNamedOptions.Configure(name, options);
                else if (name == Options.DefaultName)
                    setup.Configure(options);
            }

            foreach (IPostConfigureOptions<TOptions> postConfigure in _postConfigures)
                postConfigure.PostConfigure(name, options);
            if (_validations != null)
            {
                List<string> failureMessages = new List<string>();
                foreach (IValidateOptions<TOptions> validation in _validations)
                {
                    ValidateOptionsResult validateOptionsResult = validation.Validate(name, options);
                    if (validateOptionsResult.Failed)
                        failureMessages.AddRange(validateOptionsResult.Failures);
                }

                if (failureMessages.Count > 0)
                    throw new OptionsValidationException(name, typeof(TOptions), failureMessages);
            }

            return options;
        }
    }
}
```